# Tell NLog to render array content rather than the array's type name

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string-formatting, nlog

Consider this:

```
var myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
logger.Debug("Array content: {0}", myArray);
```

*Actual* output (using `object.ToString()`):

```
Array content: System.Int32[]
```

*Desired* output:

```
Array content: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Of course, this may be done by manually converting the `int[]` to a `string` before passing it to NLog like this:

```
logger.Debug("Array content: {0}", string.Join(", ", myArray));
```

However, I only want the array content string to be generated *if the message is actually logged* (in this case if Debug level is enabled) because of possible performance impact for larger arrays.

**--> Question:** Is there a way to tell NLog to log the contents of an array rather than its type name?

I have read a lot about renderers and so on, but did not find a way how to tell NLog to render arguments in a different way. Another approach would be a custom string format for arrays, e.g. `{0:X}`, but obviously arrays do not support any formats. Another idea would be to pass a delegate instead of the parameter itself, so that the string conversion would only happen if the delegate is actually called. However, no such overload seems to exist.

Comment: The docu makes me believe that this should already work https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#formatting-of-the-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ralf is close. NLog supports [structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging). With structured logging it also performs some [special formatting for certain data types](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#formatting-of-the-message). However, for some backwards compatibility (that I don't know the details of) if you use indexed logging like in your example [it'll skip the special formatting](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#combine-indexed-and-structured-logging).

Instead you should do something like:

```
// Name your parameter        vvvvvvv
logger.Debug("Array content: {content}", myArray);
```

NLog checks the message-template and when detecting positional-placeholders, then it uses `string.Format` that supports repeated positional values. Ex. `string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}", Environment.NewLine, "Hello", "World");`. Message Template for structured-logging does not support repeated positional values.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Sometimes it's so simple... :)